# function is not being triggered by "click" addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, it is attaching an event listener to all elements with the var tag and then triggering a function called getWords()

```
//The local database
wordBank = [
            // {word:"aprobi", translation:"to approve", count:2},
            // {word:"bati", translation:"to hit, to beat, to strike", count:1},
            // {word:"da", translation:"of", count:1}
            ];

//getting the var tags and attaching the event listeners
var wordsWritten = document.getElementsByTagName("var");

for (var i = 0; i < wordsWritten.length; i++){
    wordsWritten[i].addEventListener("click", getWords())
};

//Getting the details from the word
function getWords() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("vortarobobelo").length != 0){
        var words;
        words = document.getElementsByClassName("vortarobobelo")[0].children[0].children;

        for (var i =0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var localBank = {} //creating the local variable to store the word
            var newWord = words[i].children[0].innerText; // getting the word from the DOM
            var newTranslation = words[i].children[1].innerText; // getting the translation from the DOM

            localBank.word = newWord;
            localBank.translation = newTranslation;
            localBank.count = 0 //assuming this is the first time the user has clicked on the word

            console.log(localBank);
            wordBank.push(localBank);
            // fireBank.update(wordBank);
        }
    }
}
```

It works just fine if I just put the entire getWords() function when I'm using the for loop to attach the eventlisteners but I don't understand why this way doesn't work.

P.S: Is there a better way to break up my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
wordsWritten[i].addEventListener("click", getWords())
```

Should be

```
wordsWritten[i].addEventListener("click", getWords)
```

ie, pass a *reference to the function* not the result of calling the function